# federate azure active directory with on premise ADFS

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ws-federation, adfs3.0

I'm trying to federate on premise ADFS 3.0 instance with Azure Active Direcotry instance. The idea is to allow AAD (azure) users to authenticate to an application which trusts the ADFS instance.

- I added azure AD to **claims provider trusts** in ADFS (using it's federation metadata document path)
- then I create an application in AAD which has identifier of the ADFS (e.g. https://fs.somedomain.com/adfs/services/trust

ADFS instance then correctly displays AZURE as special realm.

The only thing I can't figure out is what should be the reply url in azure application settings, so the ADFS instance redirects authenticated request to correct application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the normal adfs/ls.

You just need to configure the URL and URI.

Refer: [Azure AD as IdP with AD FS as RP](http://cloudidentityblog.com/2013/06/16/azure-ad-as-idp-with-ad-fs-as-rp/).